# Mysql Insertion and Update

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need some help with understanding the mysql insert and update methods. I am running Mamp and I know that php and mysql are working. The way my database is set up is they have a key in the info table. The data is encrypted going into the database and decrypted when it is displayed to passbook.html. Currently data can be updated, but if the username or password is changed a new entry is placed in the database instead of updating it. How can I fix this problem to have the data update. The update should occur if the password or username are changed. If the website is changed it should create a new entry and remove the old entry.

passbook.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Passbook</title>
</head>
<body >

 <header>

<h1> My Passbook</h1></header>
</header>
<body>        
<?php
    $count = 1;
?>

 <style>
#pass a{
visibility:hidden;
}
#pass:hover a{
visibility:visible;
}
td{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
function checkBox(checkbox){
if(checkbox.checked)
    checkbox.value = 'Yes';
else
    checkbox.value = 'No';
}

function addRow(){
            var table = document.getElementById('table');
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);


            var count = document.getElementById('table').rows.length - 1;

            row.innerHTML="<td name='row' value='"+count+"'>"+count+"</td>"
                        + "<td><input name='" + count + "check' type='checkbox' value=''></input></td>"
                        + "<td><input name='" + count + "web' type='text'></input></td>"
                        + "<td><input name='" + count + "user' type='text'></input></td>"
                        + "<td><input name='" + count + "pass' type='text'></input></td>";


                        document.getElementById('custom').value = count;

            }

</script>

<form method="post" action="passbook.php">
 <table id="table" border=5;>
<th>Row #</th>
<th>Selected</th>
<th>Websites</th>
<th>Usernames</th>
<th>Passwords</th>

<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']) or die ("Could not connect");
$key = mysql_query('SELECT `key` FROM `'.$_SESSION['username'].'`.`info`');
$string = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$_SESSION['username'].'`.`passbook` WHERE 1';
$result = mysql_query($string);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $decUser = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($row['username']), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
        $decPass = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($row['password']), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
        if($row['selected'] == 1 )
            echo "<tr><td style='text-align:center;' value='".$count."'>".$count."</td>
                  <td><input type='checkbox'  name='".$count."check' value='1' checked></td>
                  <td><input type='text' name='".$count."web' value='".$row['website']."'><br></td>
                  <td id='user'><a><input type='text' name='".$count."user' value='".$decUser."'></a></td>
                  <td id='pass'><a><input type='text' name='".$count."pass' value='".$decPass."'></a></td>
                  </tr>";
        else if($row['selected'] == 0)
            echo "<tr><td style='text-align:center;' value='".$count."'>".$count."</td>
                  <td><input type='checkbox'  name='".$count."check' value='0'></td>
                  <td><input type='text' name='".$count."web' value='".$row['website']."'><br></td>
                  <td id='user'><a><input type='text' name='".$count."user' value='".$decUser."'></a></td>
                  <td id='pass'><a><input type='text' name='".$count."pass' value='".$decPass."'></a></td>
                  </tr>";
    $count++;
    }
    ?>
    </table>


    <br/>
 <input type="button" value="Add row" id="AddRow" onclick="addRow()"></input>
 <input type="submit" value="Save Table"></input>
 </form>
    <br/><br/>
 <label id="yes"></label>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function GotoPage()
 {
 var loc = document.getElementById('scroller').value;
 if(loc!="0")
 window.location = loc;
 }
 </script>


 <select id="scroller" style="height:42px; width:145px;" onchange="GotoPage()" >
 <optgroup label="Home">
<option value="homepage.html">Home</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="View Credentials" >
<option value="passbook.html" selected>Passbook</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Other" >
 <option value="settings.html" >Settings</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

</body></html>
```

passbook.php

```
session_start();

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password']) or die ("Could not connect");
$db = mysql_select_db($_SESSION['username'],$connection);
    $num = 0;

foreach ($_POST as $data => $value){
    $num = substr($data, 0 , 1);
 }
    $string = "SELECT `key` FROM `info`";
    $key = mysql_query($string) or die("failureeee");

    for($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++){
    $username = $_POST[$i.'user'];
    $password = $_POST[$i.'pass'];
    $encUser = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), substr($username,strlen($i)-1), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    $encPass = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), substr($password,strlen($i)-1), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    $website = $_POST[$i.'web'];
    echo "Encrypt" . "<br>"  . $_POST[$i.'check'] . " " . $website . " " . $encUser. " " . $encPass . "<br>";


    if(isset($_POST[$i.'check'])){
            $q = "SELECT * FROM `passbook` WHERE `website`='".$website."'";
            $select = mysql_query($q);
            while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
                if($info == $website){
                    $query = "UPDATE `passbook` SET  `selected` = '1',`username` = '".$encUser."',`password`='".$encPass."' WHERE `website`='".$website."'";
                    $run = mysql_query($query);
                }
            }
            if(!isset($query)){
                $query = "INSERT INTO `passbook` (`selected`,`website`,`username`,`password`) VALUES ('1','".$website."','".$encUser."','".$encPass."')";
                $run = mysql_query($query);
                echo "<br>INSERT web=".$website."<br>";
            }
    }
    else{
        $q = "SELECT `website` FROM `".$_SESSION['username']."`.`passbook`";
            $select = mysql_query($q);
            while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
                if($info == $website){
                    $q2 = "UPDATE `passbook` SET  `selected` = '0',`username` = '".$encUser."',`password`='".$encPass."' WHERE `website`='".$website."'";
                }

            }
            if(!isset($q2)){
                $run = mysql_query($q2);
            }
            else{
            $q2 = "INSERT INTO `passbook` (`selected`,`website`,`username`,`password`) VALUES ('0','".$website."','".$encUser."','".$encPass."')";
            $run = mysql_query($q2);
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP has major errors.

- mysql_ functions are being depreciated
- You send user submitted values directly to the database, leaving you vulnerable to SQL injection
- Your code isn't logical

In the following code you attempt to compare an array - $info - with a string - $website.

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
    if($info == $website){
        $query = "UPDATE `passbook` SET  `selected` = '1',`username` = '".$encUser."',`password`='".$encPass."' WHERE `website`='".$website."'";
        $run = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

I think what you mean to do is:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
    // $info is an array that holds the row's data.  You access an individual "cell" by referencing the column name as the key
    if($info['website'] == $website){
        $query = "UPDATE `passbook` SET  `selected` = '1',`username` = '".$encUser."',`password`='".$encPass."' WHERE `website`='".$website."'";
        $run = mysql_query($query);
    }
}
```

Then in this code you check if $q2 is set and, if it isn't, you...try to execute a query using it?  Doesn't make sense.

```
if(!isset($q2)){
    $run = mysql_query($q2);
}
```

This is opinion more than anything but...your "encryption" scheme is pointless.  You store the key right along with the encrypted data.  If someone gets access to your database (which they will if you don't fix the SQL injection issues) they will have everything they need to decrypt the data.

Comment: Thank you. What would you recommend as an encryption scheme?